# How do I loads a .json file into a deep hierarchy recursive struct with GO

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

Im trying to load a config file (config.json) into a go struct. Im using "json.Unmarshal" resource to deserialize. However,the struct never loads the full hierarchy, limmiting the struct at the second level.

That is my structs

```
//ConfigurationsMQ struct data
type ConfigurationsMQ struct {
    Rabbitmq RabbitMQ `json:"rabbitmq"`
}

//RabbitMQ struct data
    type RabbitMQ struct {
    Connections ConnectionsMQ `json:"connections"`
}

//ConnectionsMQ provide a array of connections profile
type ConnectionsMQ struct {
    Production ConnectionInfo `json:"production"`
    Local      ConnectionInfo `json:"local"`
}

//ConnectionInfo stores data to RabbitMQ connection
type ConnectionInfo struct {
    ConnectionName string `json:"ConnectionName"`
    ServerIP       string `json:"ServerIP"`
    ServerPort     string `json:"ServerPort"`
    ServerUsername string `json:"ServerUsername"`
    ServerPassword string `json:"ServerPassword"`
}
```

Thats is the function who make the work

```
//OpenConfig return the config structure
func OpenConfig() ConfigurationsMQ {
    byt, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./Utils/config.json")
    AddLog("open file action", err, true)

    var conf ConfigurationsMQ
    errJSON := json.Unmarshal(byt, &conf)
    AddLog("Unmarshal a Json file", errJSON, true)

    return conf
}
```

The used json

```
${
    "rabbitmq": {
        "connections":{
            "local":{ 
                    "ConnectionName":"Local",
                    "ServerIP" : "127.0.0.1",
                    "ServerPort": "5672",
                    "ServerUsername" : "guest",
                    "ServerPassword" : "guest"
                },
                "production":{ 
                    "ConnectionName":"Local",
                    "ServerIP" : "127.0.0.1",
                    "ServerPort": "5672",
                    "ServerUsername" : "guest",
                    "ServerPassword" : "guest"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[Ondrive Print](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArfKIORzIVWmgiS2TizvTVSTA9ju)

I just tryed a lot of tips that a found googling: Revised lower/upper case names; use of pointers; I changed the order of the declarations and tested  a hundreds ways of mount the structure. 
Using a json with just two levels works fine.

Comment: That structure isn't recursive, nor is it unusually deep. Also, everything your posted works: https://play.golang.org/p/gks58STxQLL  so there is some issue not represented in the question.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! 
the posted struct is simplest  in order the issue can easily noted. vscode debbuguer is the problem.